# Can you individually use a SOFLAM to your advantage as recon class?

Tags: battlefield-3

I tried for awhile to use the SOFLAM to laser target air vehicles, but no one else on the team was hitting them with javelins or laser guided tanks.  (Same problem when I jump in a tank in the CITV station).

Is there any way to use the SOFLAM individually to destroy enemy vehicles?

Comment: You can pick up engineer kits.

Comment: equip SOFLAM and guided shell on tank. Set up SOFLAM. get back in tank.

Comment: @AustinBath Thanks for the help! You probably want to post that as an answer, not a comment. (Would help you earn rep as well!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No not really but you could switch kits. A lot of people forget how useful switching kits can really be. I sometimes set up a SOFLAM as Recon and leave it to designate targets automatically while I find myself a javalin.

Comment: At least on PC, I think the SOFLAM is now destroyed if you try that.

Comment: I seem to remember a while back (many patches ago) that it was possible to lay down a SOFLAM, die, and pick engineer, and it would still be there if it was not destroyed. That may indeed no longer be the case. However, it should be very possible (though I have not personally done this myself) to pick up and use a Javelin which is a part of a kit dropped by an enemy or friendly engineer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it isn't too useful:

Set up your SOFLAM, aim it in a useful direction, and then disconnect. Now jump into a vehicle with the Guided Shell or Guided Missile unlock. Wait until an enemy vehicle blunders through the area the SOFLAM is sitting and watching.

If you want help from teammates, you should always **announce** that you are making laser-designations, because *most players can't see them*. Only players who are already carrying laser-related equipment can see the diamond-indicator. Your engineers who have SMAWs probably don't even know that there's a SOFLAM, so they won't bother to change to Javelin.

Answer (score 1):

No, there really isn't. If no one is using your targetting, you're better off doing something else with your time. The piddling amount of points you get for laser designation really isn't worth it.

I do agree it is a bit deflating. I especially hate being in the CITV station because it's so hard to coordinate with a regular tank driver to have guided missiles.

Answer (score 1):

Using the SOFLAM isn't really worth all that many points anyway, but if you can find a good squad they will be glad to spawn with a javalin and make use of your targeting. The SOFLAM is very powerful and can basically take out any target with ease with two + coordinated players so DICE made it a little tedious to use properly. If you could just drop a SOFLAM die and then spawn as an engineer then there would be no helicopters planes or tanks alive in the entire game. It is very satisfying to designate a pesky chopper and watch it have no chance of evading your missle haha.